# Haskell arrays are too strict?

Tags: haskell

I'm implementing [Smith-Waterman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm) algorithm in Haskell, but I'm getting a runtime error: `<<loop>>`

In my implementation, I'm trying to use the lazy nature of Haskell, so I use an immutable array `resarray` to store lazy and recursive stubs which also refer to the array itself (in a dependency chain `resarray` depends on `zippedList` which depends on `cellDef` which depends on `cell` which depends on `resarray`  ). Each cell refers to a cell with lesser indexes, so the computation should be viable... albeit it doesn't behave that way.

As a proof of concept, I tried the following in ghci:

```
let arr = listArray (0,3) [0, arr ! 0, arr ! 1, arr ! 2 ]
```

and it worked. However my longer computation ends up being strict for some unknown reason.

Here is my code (the complete version, together with a test script, is [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5363697/hs.zip) ):

```
buildSWArray:: 
    WordSequence ->
    WordSequence ->
    SWMatrix
buildSWArray ws1 ws2 = let
        rows = arrLen ws1
        cols = arrLen ws2
        im = matToLinearIndex rows cols
        mi = linToMatIndex rows cols
        totsize = rows * cols
        ixarr = [0 .. (totsize-1)]
        cell i j 
            | i < 0 || j < 0 = 0
        cell i j  = 
            resarr !  (im i j ) 
        cellDef k | k == 0 = (None,0)
        cellDef k = 
            let
                (i,j) = mi k
                upwards = cell (i-1) j
                leftwards = cell i (j-1)
                diag = cell (i-1) (j-1) 
                -- One up if match, -5 if not match
                c = if ws1 ! i == ws2 ! j then 1 else (-5)
                hi = maximum [ 0, diag + c, upwards - 3, leftwards - 3]
            in 
                -- Dirty way of guessing which one was picked up
                case hi of 
                   hi | hi == 0  -> ( None, 0)
                   hi | hi == upwards - 3 -> ( Upwards, hi)
                   hi | hi == leftwards - 3 -> ( Leftwards, hi )
                   hi | hi == diag + c -> (Diag, hi )
        zippedList = [ cellDef k | k <- ixarr ]
        resarr =  IA.listArray (0,(totsize - 1)) [ score | (way,score) <- zippedList ]
        wayarr = IA.listArray (0,(totsize - 1)) [ way | (way,score) <- zippedList ]
    in 
        SWMatrix rows cols wayarr resarr
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: my guess is you've failed to 'tie the knot' properly. Check your base cases and verify your assumption that your recursive arguments are decreasing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're being strict by pattern-matching,

```
resarr =  IA.listArray (0,(totsize - 1)) [ score | (way,score) <- zippedList ]
wayarr = IA.listArray (0,(totsize - 1)) [ way | (way,score) <- zippedList ]
```

that forces the array elements to be read while constructing, which does not work.

Simple example:

```
module LazyArr where

import Data.Array.IArray

test :: Int -> (Array Int Int, Array Int Int)
test n =
    let zippedList = map foo [0 .. n]
        foo :: Int -> (Int,Int)
        foo i
            | i == 0 = (0,0)
            | arrOne ! (i-1) < arrTwo ! (i-1) = (2,1)
            | even i = (i,arrTwo ! (i-1))
            | otherwise = (arrOne ! (i-1),i)
        arrOne = listArray (0,n) $ map fst zippedList -- [a | (a,b) <- zippedList]
        arrTwo = listArray (0,n) $ map snd zippedList -- [b | (a,b) <- zippedList]
    in (arrOne, arrTwo)
```

works, but with the list comprehensions instead of `map fst` resp. `map snd`, it loops.

So using the lazier version `map fst zippedList` and `map snd zippedList` should work (as should a lazy pattern in the list comprehensions `[way | ~(way,score) <- zippedList]`), at least I don't see further problems in the dependencies.

By pattern-matching on the pair, `cellDef k` must be evaluated far enough to see that the top-level constructor is indeed a `(,)`. For that, the branch taken must be determined, and that requires inspecting the contained values of earlier elements. But while the array is created, these cannot yet be obtained.

> Each cell refers to a cell with lesser indexes, so the computation should be viable

That, however, isn't important. All you need is that there are no dependency cycles, and every chain leads to a defined base case.

Comment: Excellent! Solved now. All in all, it's amazing that I don't get anything worse from the Haskell runtime and just a very measured <<loop>>

Comment: But how come the `fst` and `snd` do not use lazy patterns in their source?

Comment: @is7s There's no point in using a lazy pattern there. A call to `fst` won't be evaluated until its result is needed [unless the optimiser finds it can and should evaluate it early]. And when its result is needed, `fst` has to deconstruct its argument.